# How to configure spring oauth?

Tags: java, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have 2 web applications:

1. Resource Server (@EnableResourceServer)
2. auth app (@EnableAuthorizationServer)

They are mapped to one database.

I would like to split database for 2: one for client app and the second one for tokens.

```
Question: How client app should be configured correctly with oauth?
```

My current flow:

- Resource Server get request with token
- spring security checks token in database

May be the best flow is to isolate auth app and database and flow should be something like this:

- Resource Server get request token
- and Resource Server makes a request to auth web app (OAuth Server) to verify token
- auth app (OAuth Server) spring security checks token in database

?

Let me know if I misunderstand any point about oauth. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use the auth server for checking tokens you need a `RemoteTokenServices` (or the equivalent). If the server is a Spring Oauth sever (using `@EnableAuthorizationServer`) there should be a /check_token endpoint.

N.B. It might be a good idea to read the spec and get the terminology straight (your "client app" is a "resource server".